# Eclipse auto detect includes and macros for multiple compilers

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on a project that uses Eclipse to build an embedded application for several different platforms.  Right now I have it set up to use a different build configuration to determine which compiler is used to build but I'm having trouble getting the index to work properly.

The core of the problem is that I have some files that are platform specific and simply won't compile anywhere else (e.g. setting hardware registers for an ARM won't work on a PowerPC).  Building is easy as I'm using a custom makefile so I can just exclude sources from different builds.  The Eclipse indexer however doesn't know that so it tries to index both files at the same time which causes problems due to different compilers having different default include directories and macros defined.  I've figured out how to change the discovery options discover one compiler or the other but I can't get it to find both at once (unless I manually add each include directory and #define but I'd like to avoid that if possible).

Is there a way to automatically discover the include paths and #defines for two different compilers in the same project?  Alternatively, is it possible to tell Eclipse not to try parsing files that aren't used in the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.  Under the C/C++ General > Code Analysis section you can select certain files/folders to be excluded.  I turned off errors about unresolved symbols, functions and types and now it works fine.